# Git fetch tags only on a specific branch?

Tags: git, git-refspec

I am using

```
git fetch origin feature/blabla
```

to be really specific what I want to fetch.

- However this does not fetch tags which are currently on `feature/blabla`.
- A `git fetch` only (supposed the branch is checkedout) fetches the
  tags too.

Is it possible to use my version and also fetch the tags
along? (I dont want to fetch all tags with `git fetch --tags`).
Especially this is usefull when on another branch.

Comment: What difference what tags get fetched? They are tiny. So just `git fetch -t origin feature/blabla`

Comment: They are tiny? They import a whole git tree if potential from somewhere else... So no they are not tiny? Or are they?

Comment: Its a ref as any other ref... (like branch)...?

Comment: @Gabriel I just rewrite the answer: that might be actually supported.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check first if adding --tags does import *all* tags.

As seen in [git/git commit 5328456](https://github.com/git/git/commit/532845604de9b3fe7c651fe2546f20043b8cd7c1), the `git fetch` man page used to say:

> By default, tags are auto-followed.
>
> This means that when fetching from a remote, any tags on the remote that point to objects that exist in the local repository are fetched.

So if you fetch only one branch, only the tags referring that branch should be fetched.

The [OP Gabriel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/293195/gabriel) reports [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65711714/git-fetch-tags-only-on-a-specific-branch/65715823?noredirect=1#comment116190903_65715823) that:

```
git fetch --tags --prune --prune-tags origin feature/blabla
```

Although it does not work, since `--all` still fetches all tags.

So the behavior must have change,d and tags are no longer auto-followed.
Git would have to consider each tag, in order to check if it contains (reference a commit of) the branch you want to fetch.
That would delay considerably the fetch operation itself.

So for now, `--tags` (meaning `refs/tags/*`) is the only option.

Or a convoluted script which would:

- fetch tags in a separate local clone
- check locally for each imported tag if they are referencing a branch
- fetch that single tag from the separate local clone to your original local cloned repository.

Comment: Hm... thats what I was thinking as well. 
So I have now success with
`git fetch --tags --prune --prune-tags origin feature/blabla`
Where `--prune` and `--prune-tags` is sugar to clean up local tags which are not on the remote.

Comment: @Gabriel Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: But no it does not work: It fetches still all tags... sadly

Comment: @Gabriel So the behavior must have changed, which is why https://github.com/git/git/commit/532845604de9b3fe7c651fe2546f20043b8cd7c1 removed the auto-followed option.

Comment: @Gabriel I have edited the answer to reflect that behavior change.

Comment: Thx, but why `git fetch --prune --prune-tags origin feature/blabla` doesnt fetch the tag is kind of strange... Since that is somehwo implied by the doc

Comment: @Gabriel I think it does fetch, then it prunes.

Comment: Sadly no, you can leave --prune off it still does not..